# I am trying to put an imageicon in my gui but it doesn't appear when I run the code. Can somebody tell me how to fix it

Tags: java

This is the code that I am using right now. When i run the code the image doesn't show.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Interface {

    private static JLabel name;
    private static ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("DigiD.png");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Panel
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(new Color(255, 145, 77, 255));

        //Titel van de app
        name = new JLabel("Food 4 U");
        name.setFont(new Font("Gill Sans Ultra Bold", Font.BOLD, 20));
        name.setBounds(135, 1, 1000, 50);

        JLabel logo = new JLabel(image);
        panel.add(logo);

        //Frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setSize(400, 1000);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(255, 145, 77, 255));
        frame.add(panel);

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. That would indicate your image is not found. Use `ImageIO` to read your image and your will get an error message if it is not found.

Comment: `ImageIcon(String)` assumes that the named resource is located within the "working directory".  `ImageIcon` will also not notify of when it can't load a resource.  You should consider "embedding" your resources and using `ImageIO.read` to load them instead

Comment: When I hover over ("DigiD.png") it shows me the image so the image is found however it doesn't show when I run the code. The image is there since any text I've put in the GUI gets pushed aside but it doesn't display.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me. Make sure the image is inside the correct folder of your project. (directly inside the top folder with the name of the entire project)